# "botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region." when deploying to ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkI5yeMFRK8&t=2400s) tutorial to deploy to ECS using CDK, but when I deploy I get this error after deployment

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

Here is what I am deploying.

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import environ

from aws_cdk import core as cdk

from ecs_test.ecs_test_stack import EcsTestStack

_env=cdk.Environment(account=environ["CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT"], region='ap-southeast-2')
app = cdk.App()
EcsTestStack(app, "EcsTestStackV3", env=_env)
app.synth()
```

ecs_test_stack.py

```
from aws_cdk import core, aws_ecs_patterns, aws_ec2, aws_ecs


class EcsTestStack(core.Stack):

def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
    super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

    _container_image = aws_ecs.ContainerImage.from_asset(
        directory=".",
        file='Dockerfile.ECS_Test',
        exclude=["cdk.out"]
    )

    vpc = aws_ec2.Vpc(self, "ecs-test-vpc-v3", max_azs=3)

    cluster = aws_ecs.Cluster(self, "ecs-test-cluster-v3", vpc=vpc)

    cluster.add_capacity("ecs-autoscaling-capacity-v3",
                         instance_type=aws_ec2.InstanceType("t2.small"),
                         min_capacity=1,
                         max_capacity=3)

    self.ecs_test = aws_ecs_patterns.QueueProcessingEc2Service(
        self,
        "ECS_Test_Pattern_v3",
        cluster=cluster,
        cpu=512,
        memory_limit_mib=512,
        image=_container_image,
        min_scaling_capacity=1,
        max_scaling_capacity=5
    )
```

Dockerfile.ECS_Test

```
from alpine:3.8

RUN apk add -U python3 py3-pip && pip3 install awscli boto3

COPY ./ecs_test/queue_service.py /queue_service.py

CMD ["/queue_service.py","receive"]
```

queue_service.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from boto3 import resource
from os import getenv
from time import sleep
from random import randrange
from sys import argv


def get_queue_details():
    sqs = resource('sqs')
    print(getenv('QUEUE_NAME'))
    return sqs.get_queue_by_name(QueueName=getenv('QUEUE_NAME'))


def receive():
    queue = get_queue_details()
    while True:
        for message in queue.receive_messages():
            print("MESSAGE CONSUMED: {}".format(message.body))
            print(message.delete())
            sleep(1)


def send(num_messages=100):
    queue = get_queue_details()
    for _num in range(num_messages):
        _rand = randrange(1000)
        print(queue.send_message(MessageBody=str(_rand)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        if argv[1] == 'send':
            send()
        if argv[1] == 'receive':
            receive()
    except IndexError as I:
        print("Please pass either send or receive.\n./queue_service.py <send> <receive>")
        exit(200)
```

queue_service.py works well when it runs locally on my system, but when I deploy using CDK and fill my queue up, I get the `botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.` error.

Question:
How do I set the region on my ECS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must inform Boto3 in which region you want to use the sqs resource.

Set `region_name` in queue_service.py for sqs resource.

```
sqs = resource('sqs', region_name='us-west-2')
```

OR

set `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable in queue_service.py

```
os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-west-2'
```

OR

Set `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` environment variable in `Dockerfile`

```
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

OR

Set environment variable in `ECS task definition`

Comment: Note the reason it works on OP's workstation is likely that they set a default region in their `~/.aws/config`.

Comment: How would I make this more generic and not have to hard code the region?

Comment: One way or another way, you need to mention the region. Another option is set ENV is Dockerfile. This avoid hardcoding in your code. Or in your ECS task definition file, add AWS_DEFAULT_REGION env

Comment: I have a default regioni in ```~/.aws/config``` but it still throws the error: botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

Comment: @momo668 where it throwing the error? And what command throwing the error ?

Comment: It's throwing error inside a docker container that have ```~/.aws/config``` mapped but I just end up specifying environment variables through the client API